# React Native: memory is not released when navigating away from FlatList view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I'm on `"react-native": "0.53.3"`. When navigating to a view with a FlatList containing ~100 components and then navigating back, not all the memory is released, which means that after a few navigations my app is consuming too much memory and crashes. This is my flatlist component which renders `comment.js`

```
return (
        <Container style={{ flex: 1}}>
            <FlatList
                data={comments}
                keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                renderItem={this.renderComment}
                removeClippedSubviews
            />
        </Container>
    );
```

comment.js looks pretty much like this:

```
return (
        <View>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.toggleCollapse}>
                {this.renderHeaderWithBorder(depth)}
            </TouchableHighlight>

            <Collapsible collapsed={this.state.collapsed} align="top">
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.toggleCollapse}>
                    {this.renderBodyWithBorder(depth)}
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </Collapsible>
        </View>
    );
```

I've noticed that if i change comment.js to render a simple `Text` component the problem goes away (the app sits around 300mb with high usage)

I'm using `"react-navigation": "1.1.1"` and redux.

It seems to me that the memory for each new comment list isn't being released when the component is unmounted, is there anyway I can mitigate this?

[image]